# How to connect via specific network interface?

Tags: linux, debian, ppp, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to connect a Raspberry Pi to the Internet via a 3G modem.

I'm ssh'ing into it via ethernet (eth0), I have the 3G connection up and running (ppp0).

How can I connect to all external addresses via ppp0? I don't want to disconnect eth0 as that is how I'm connecting to the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your network configuration so that ppp0 is the default gateway.

Comment: And, how would I do that via the command line?

Comment: `route` will let you modify the routing table, but for a permanent solution you'd want to modify the configuration files. Dunno which ones for Debian though.

Comment: Forgive me, is it enough to say "sudo route add default dev ppp0"?

Comment: Sounds about right. You may need to remove the existing default though.